# Want to restrict the value of a MySQL field to specific range (Decimal values)

Tags: mysql, decimal, database-schema, sqldatatypes

I want to restrict the value of a field in a row of a table to a specific range. Is it possible to restrict my relationship_level field **to [0.00 to 1.00]**?

At the moment I am using DECIMAL(2,2), it wouldn't allow DECIMAL(1,2) as M must be >= D. I assume a data type of DECIMAL(2,2) will actually allow values from 00.00 up to 99.99?

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
    from_user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    to_user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    relationship_level DECIMAL(2,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (from_user_id, to_user_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (from_user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (to_user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    INDEX relationship_from_to (to_user_id, from_user_id, relationship_level)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Is there a better way to do this, can anyone foresee any limitations?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you really want to restrict the values from `0.00` to `1.00`, you should use a `DECIMAL(3,2)` datatype and an FK referencing to a "stable" (reference) table, with just 101 rows. Much like the answer to your other question: [Limit the value of a MySQL datatype to a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249695/limit-the-value-of-a-mysql-datatype-to-a-specific-range-preferably-not-enum)

Comment: Perfect. I imagined it would involve something similar to this (with a FK referencing another table restricting the range)  I just wondered if there existed a more 'efficient' method to the previous approach. Many thanks.

Comment: There is one other possibility but I haven't used it so I'm not aware of any problems. Define an updatable View using the `WITH CHECK OPTION`. But then, you'll have to use only that View instead of the Table (at least for Inserts and Updates): [CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate a check constraint in MySQL using triggers.

For example, if you want to force all values larger than 1.00 to be stored as 1.00, you could do so with 2 triggers like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_b_ins_relationships $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_b_ins_relationships BEFORE INSERT ON relationships FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.relationship_level > 1
  THEN
    SET new.relationship_level = 1;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_b_upd_relationships $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_b_upd_relationships BEFORE UPDATE ON relationships FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.relationship_level > 1
  THEN
    SET new.relationship_level = 1;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Triggers sounds excellent, I think I'll be using them to solve this problem and in a few other places now. Thanks!

Comment: The apple sounded excellent (and looked yummy) to Adam, too. [Are database triggers evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460316/are-database-triggers-evil)

Comment: I assert this is a reasonable use of triggers, especially given the fact that MySQL does not support check constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `DECIMAL(2,2)` will allow a decimal of up to 2 places, BOTH of which are allocated to decimal places.  The maximum value for that field would be `0.99`, and the minimum would be `0.00`.

To restrict values to `00.00` to `99.99`, use `DECIMAL(4,2) UNSIGNED`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying the range I would actually get from using DECIMAL(2,2)=[0.00 to 0.99]. Is it actually possible to limit it in such a way to achieve a range of [0.00 to 1.00], I'm assuming it would involve alternatives to the DECIMAL datatype.

Comment: No, you can't have from `[0.00 to 1.00]` restricted. With `DECIMAL(3,2) UNSIGNED` you could have from 0.00 to 9.99

Comment: You could restrict it using BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE TRIGGERS.  You could either coerce the values or trigger an error by setting a NOT NULL column to NULL in the trigger.