# SQL Table structure in phpmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin tool to construct a database. I have created a table : `Vehicles`. Whenever I try to put some condition on any of the fields it does not work. e.g. I try to put a restriction on the `Age` field so that `Age` `>10`. E.g.

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicles
ADD CHECK (Age>10)
```

But this doesn't work and whenever I enter any value less than ten the record is saved in the table

Comment: `CHECK` is not supported in MySQL

Comment: @AbdulManaf To be precise: the (correct) *syntax* for a check constraint is supported, it's just silently ignored (like so many things in MySQL)

Comment: as @AbdulManaf says `CHECK`is not supported, you should read this: [Simulate CHECK on mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575604/want-to-restrict-the-value-of-a-mysql-field-to-specific-range-decimal-values)