# How would i make a double that doesn't go higher than 5?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, check-constraints

I want to make a double in a table, lets say its a restaurant for example

```
   create table Restaurant(
    RestaurantName varchar(17),
    rating double?
    );
```

Basically if you wanted it to be rated out of 5 the Restaurant, how would you go on doing that? So it could be like 4.25 or 3.91 or anything from 0-5.0

Comment: Why would I rate a restaurant 3.14159265358979323846264338 or something instead of 3 or 4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to restrict the value of a MySQL field to specific range (Decimal values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575604/want-to-restrict-the-value-of-a-mysql-field-to-specific-range-decimal-values)

Comment: @SalmanA, they have perfectly round pizzas, however average tasting.

Comment: @SalmanA it's not that. Its meant to be 3.25, two decimals not... as many as u did xD

Comment: Don't use `double for this.  Use `numeric`/`decimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use a check constraint:

```
create table restaurant(
    restaurantname varchar(17),
    rating decimal(5, 4) check(rating between 0 and 5)
);
```

You probably don't need double precision to store a rating. I changed the datatype to a decimal, with 4 decimal positions.

I also assumed that you want a value between 0 and 5 *inclusive*. If you wanted to exclude the upper bound, then:

```
    rating decimal(5, 4) check(rating >= 0 and rating < 5)
```

In earlier versions, you would typically need to implement the logic with a trigger.

Comment: Exactly what I want except possibly just to 2 decimals, thankyou though!

Comment: I'm getting Error Code: 1427. For float(M,D), double(M,D) or decimal(M,D), M must be >= D